# .net Membership deny login

Tags: asp.net-membership

I've been working with the .net login for a long time now, but my latest project calls for some not so great coding.

I have one database which contains the tables etc for .net membership.
There are 4 roles:

- Admin
- BasicAdmin
- PowerAdmin
- Member

Now the top 3 are able to log into the Admin system, but I want to deny login for those in the role Member, I have added in the following to the webconfig:

```
<authorization>
  <deny roles="Member"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

this works, to an extent. It redirects the user who is in the role 'Member' to the login page, but it does not give the message login failed, as you would get when you are not registered and you enter wrong data.

The members can log into a members area of the site which will be for arguement sake off limits to admins.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong, am I missing something or is this not possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your members can login and get to the member content but are then redirected when they attempt to get to something in the admin section.  It is working by design.  The member wouldn't get a failed login message because they have not failed to login, rather they are denied access.

Throughout the application you can check as a person is trying to go to page that they can't access and fire off a message that they don't have access but that is extra work but doable.

You can also modify your application in such a way that links to certain sections of the site only show if the user is in the right role.  For example, Roles.IsUserInRole("role") will check the currently logged in identity / user is in a role.  There is also the LoginView control in 2.0 that you can wrap controls in that do this nicely for you.

EDIT: Clarification based on your first comment.

This is how the roles provider is designed.  It redirects you to the login page when you try to access a page you have been denied in the web.config for.

You could do a couple of things:

Remove the deny statements for the groups in the web.config and then do one of two things or both:

Use the loginview control and encapsulate the functionality for the "admin" role in the admin view and then display a message to the "member" role that they don't have access.

And/Or write code on the page load event for a page checking the roles and presenting a message and/or redirecting a user to another page.

OR leave the deny statement in the web.config for the groups AND

on the page load event of the login page do something like

```
        If  Me.User.Identity IsNot Nothing and Me.User.Identity.Isauthenticated Then
          If Me.User.IsInRole("admin") Then
            Response.Redirect("~NoAccessToMemberStuff.htm")
          Else If Me.User.IsInRole("member") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/NoAccessToAdminStuff.htm")
          End If
    End If
```

Comment: Ok, I missed a bit of further information which might help.

The admin side of the application is actually a seperate website.
ie
www.mysite.com -- the site
admin.mysite.com -- admin site

So rather than saying you dont have access, which would show the peron attempting to login that their details do access this site to some point, I want to just show the "login detail wrong" validation message that login shows but default with an incorrect login.

I am also using 3.5

I dont like the redirect to "your log in failed page" as really it didnt its just that is the only page you can see.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit. I thought I might be stuck doing it like that. Oh well thanks for your help I'll give it a whirl when i'm back in on Monday. Cheers for now.