# Utilize a Banned Role - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<location path="CreateArticle">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny roles="banned"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

The code above works fine but when I ban myself, It automatically redirects to the login page. I don't want this, If a person is banned I want it to redirect to a banned page. is this possible in MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can check inside your controller if the user is banned and make a proper decision

```
if (User.IsInRole("Banned"))
        {
            // do something here
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using the built in asp.net membership/roles provider.  This is the design of the system.

You can code around this yourself.  Here's an example of this:

[.net Membership deny login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306300/net-membership-deny-login/1306650#1306650)

The code in this sample was with web forms in mind not MVC so you will need to adapt it but it should get you down the right path.